# GODOT - C# referencing current node

Tags: c#, godot

I have specific problem in coding in GODOT(I'm using C#, I'm new to godot). I need to reference current node that has attached script. Let's say - I have 3 buttons and all of them inherits from base class called "menuButton" that has attached script called "menuScript" that includes code for changing text color onHover. And I need to reference current node, so that I can change the color of child label node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples, there may be more combinations:

```
private CollisionShape2D charCollider;
private Node3D child1; //godot4 new name
[Export] public NodePath characterPath; //this define on editor
private Control control;
private Camera camera;

public override void _Ready(){
    //by string path 
    char_collider = (CollisionShape2D) GetNode("child0/char_collider"); 
    //by child index or null if no exists second child 
    child1 = GetChildOrNull<Node3D>(1);
    //by nodePath with editor
    control = GetNodeOrNull<Control>(characterPath);
    //"this" is not necessary but work
    var node = this.GetNode("banana") as Node;
    //you can use "parent()" or ("../..")
    camera = node.GetParent();
    camera= node.GetNode("..");//same
    //Any Node inheritance can use these functions
    node = camera.GetNode("child");
    //You can use uniques names on editor
    GetNode<Button>("%buPlay").Pressed += onClickPlay;
}
```

Comment: absolutelly a lovely answer, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`this`

Typically, you don't need to do this. Functions and parameters of the node can be accessed without a node reference

- Child of current node: `GetChild(i)` (shortened version of `this.GetChild(i)`)
- Name of current node: `GetName()` (shortened version of `this.GetName()`)

You may need to use `this` for other functions that have a node parameter. Most notably:
- `Connect("signal", this, "MyMethod")`

Answer (score 2):

**I got it**

Just use GetNode(this.GetPath())

Comment: This isn't a good method! You may want to check the answer I posted...

Also, for future questions, you should mark answers as correct if they answer the problem, even if you solved it yourself.

Comment: Just saw it now. BTW, I don't know why, but referencing "this" does not work for me.